# huggingface fine tuning distilbert-base-uncased and then using pipeline throws error KeyError: 'logits'

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am referring to the [model](https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad). I am fine tuning that model. Before fine tuning I could use `pipeline` as below

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

model_check = "distilbert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_check)

from transformers import pipeline

from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification


modelz = (AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_check))

classifier = pipeline("text-classification", model=modelz,tokenizer=tokenizer)

custom_tweet = "I saw a movie today and it was really good."
preds = classifier(custom_tweet, return_all_scores=True)
preds



[[{'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.5338158011436462},
  {'label': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.46618416905403137}]]


type(modelz)
transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_distilbert.DistilBertForSequenceClassification
```

then I am using `from transformers import Trainer` to train the model and saving it. But after that I havent been able to use `pipeline` :(

```
saved_model_path='/zyz'

trainer.save_model(saved_model_path)


model_saved=AutoModel.from_pretrained(saved_model_path)
tokenizer_saved=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(saved_model_path)

type(model_saved)
#transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_distilbert.DistilBertModel   

from transformers import pipeline

classifier = pipeline("text-classification", model=model_saved,tokenizer=tokenizer_saved)

custom_tweet = "I saw a movie today and it was really good."
preds = classifier(custom_tweet)#, return_all_scores=True)




The model 'DistilBertModel' is not supported for text-classification. Supported models are ['FNetForSequenceClassification', 'GPTJForSequenceClassification', 'LayoutLMv2ForSequenceClassification', 'RemBertForSequenceClassification', 'CanineForSequenceClassification', 'RoFormerForSequenceClassification', 'BigBirdPegasusForSequenceClassification', 'BigBirdForSequenceClassification', 'ConvBertForSequenceClassification', 'LEDForSequenceClassification', 'DistilBertForSequenceClassification', 'AlbertForSequenceClassification', 'CamembertForSequenceClassification', 'XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification', 'MBartForSequenceClassification', 'BartForSequenceClassification', 'LongformerForSequenceClassification', 'RobertaForSequenceClassification', 'SqueezeBertForSequenceClassification', 'LayoutLMForSequenceClassification', 'BertForSequenceClassification', 'XLNetForSequenceClassification', 'MegatronBertForSequenceClassification', 'MobileBertForSequenceClassification', 'FlaubertForSequenceClassification', 'XLMForSequenceClassification', 'ElectraForSequenceClassification', 'FunnelForSequenceClassification', 'DebertaForSequenceClassification', 'DebertaV2ForSequenceClassification', 'GPT2ForSequenceClassification', 'GPTNeoForSequenceClassification', 'OpenAIGPTForSequenceClassification', 'ReformerForSequenceClassification', 'CTRLForSequenceClassification', 'TransfoXLForSequenceClassification', 'MPNetForSequenceClassification', 'TapasForSequenceClassification', 'IBertForSequenceClassification'].

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-92-cf10c8e85589> in <module>()
      4 
      5 custom_tweet = "I saw a movie today and it was really good."
----> 6 preds = classifier(custom_tweet)#, return_all_scores=True)

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in __getitem__(self, k)
   1952         if isinstance(k, str):
   1953             inner_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in self.items()}
-> 1954             return inner_dict[k]
   1955         else:
   1956             return self.to_tuple()[k]

KeyError: 'logits'
```

I am confused about 2 things -

1. why does it say `The model 'DistilBertModel' is not supported for text-classification. Supported models are`  in the second part of the code when the first part runs without any problems. I tried `type(modelz)` and `type(model_saved)` and I see that the trainer is being saved differently. Why is that? How should I save the trianer so that it's class doesnt change?
2. Why does it throw error  `KeyError: 'logits'`

update 1================================found answer

I fixed it by changing as below

```
model_saved=AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(saved_model_path)
```

Comment: Can you try with DistilbertForSequenceClassification model?

Comment: I feel that I am doing the same as I am using `AutoModelForSequenceClassification` and then `modelz = (AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_check))`